# How to track specific Referrals with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, url, referrer

How do I have to alter a Referral link to my website to specifically track it with Google Analytics? I already discovered the [URL Builder](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578) but isn't there are shorter way?

For example:

- `http://domain.com?ref=special` => easy to filter/track/view in Google Analytics

How are you doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own URL using the URL builder (or your own flavor of it if you want the whole thing to be automated) and then assign it to an affiliate ID and store it in a database. Then whenever that affiliate ID is used redirect to the URL with the Google Analytics code in it. That's how my clients are doing it. It works like a charm.